# What is more efficient, an algorithm to calculate x^2 or one to calculate the square root of a number?

Tags: algorithm, root, square

What are the more efficients algorithms to calculate x^2 and x^(1/2)?
And between the best of both what is more efficient?
The problem I'm trying to solve consists in find the nth 'green' number, where
a N is a 'green' number if N^2 ends with n. For example 5^2=25, 376^2=141376.
Here is some code I tried but takes to much time to compute the 10th number:

What I've done consist basically in take a number i of x digits obtain the
last x digits of i, without making the whole power and compare this last x digits with i, if coincide sum 1 to the accumulator variable. I was thinking to avord the problem in another way, instead of calculate i^2 for every number, calculate i^(1/2) of the number and make the same comparition maybe that improve a little the program because only has to take in account the numbers that end with 0,1,4,9,6,5. But I know the really improvement come with
thinking the problem in another way, of which I don't have the slightest idea.

```
def special_multiply(sa):
reverse_num = reversed(sa)
accumulator = 0
for i, digit in enumerate(reverse_num):
    temp_chunk = sa[i:]
    temp_pow = "".join(['1', '0' * i])
    accumulator += int(digit) * int(temp_chunk) * int(temp_pow)
return accumulator % int("".join(['1', '0' * (i + 1)]))

def green(n):
count = 0
i = 0
while count <= n:
    i += 1
    si = str(i)
    if si == str(special_multiply(si)):
        count += 1
return i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put another way, a `k`-digit number `x` is green if it satisfies

```
 2           k
x  = x mod 10 .
```

The [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) implies that this equation is equivalent to two equations

```
 2          k
x  = x mod 2

 2          k
x  = x mod 5 .
```

Solving these equations is equivalent to finding roots of the polynomial `x^2 - x = x (x - 1)` modulo a power of `2` or `5`. Mod `2` and mod `5`, there are two solutions, namely `x = 0` and `x = 1`. Since the derivative of the polynomial, `2x - 1` is nonzero mod `2` and mod `5` for both solutions, [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) implies that `0` and `1` are in fact the only solutions mod the prime powers.

Hence there are four solutions mod `10^k`, which has residues `0` or `1` mod `2^k` and `5^k`. For example, `376 mod 5^3 = 1` and `376 mod 2^3 = 0`. For each `k`, we can use the Chinese remainder theorem to find the four solutions (one of which will be zero and hence ineligible).

Comment: Oh! this is good very good, let me see if I get it right. If I want to check if a number say let's say x=6188999442576576769103890995893380022607743740081787109376 is a solution I have only to check if 6188999442576576769103890995893380022607743740081787109376 mod 5^58 = 0 or 1 and the same with 2^58.

Comment: Yes, though ideally you just solve the equation with extended Euclid and avoid checking in the first place (except that the solution is long enough).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the algorithm to calculate x^2 is very simple - just compute x*x . 
Lets say x ~ 2^n then the calculation of x * x is in O(n) (2^n can be represented by n bits , multiplexing is O(1) there for if we do multiplexing of n bits it will be O(n)).
On contrary,  x^(1/2) it is pretty complicated Calculation and includes number of iteration, and of course- you actually need to write an algorithm and not the line x*x.